# Remove (known) password from PDF without Acrobat Pro?

Tags: pdf, passwords, adobe-acrobat, password-protection

We have a number of documents that had been given to us password protected. We have the password for each document, but now we want to remove the protection so that our employees can freely access the PDF's on our fileserver. Is there a way or an open-source tool that can remove the protection? I want to emphasize that I am **not** looking for a cracker or something, we **own** the documents and have the passwords, we just want to avoid having to buy Acrobat to remove the protection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One easy way would be to use Google Chrome. The trick is to use the print function to make a new pdf document:

1. Use the built in pdf reader in Chrome to open the document
2. When prompted, enter the password
3. Go to the File menu and select Print, instead of sending it to a printer select destination printer as "Save as PDF"
4. The password should have been removed on the new document

Source: [labnol.org](https://www.labnol.org/software/remove-pdf-password/20017/)

Comment: Sadly, though, it takes 300 times the file space!

Answer (score 1):

Sejda PDF can help you remove the password restrictions from PDF documents, given you own the documents and have the password.

https://www.sejda.com/unlock-pdf

Free service for documents up to 200 pages or 50 Mb and 3 tasks per hour.

If you prefer to process your files locally instead of online you can use Sejda Desktop: https://www.sejda.com/desktop

I'm one of the developers.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with https://www.ilovepdf.com/unlock_pdf I use it and works like a charm with no limitations.

as per the site Documentation:
To remove the password from a PDF file, upload the document from your device or straight from your Google Drive or Dropbox account.

Then click the 'Unlock PDF' button. Our tool will unlock your document by removing its password. Check the 'Unlock PDF' limits for each account type.

Of course you said that you own the docs and have the password so I think is a good fit for your needs.

Regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1126985)